# How can i create Custom Style for styleBar of UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

Can i creates my custom style for styleBar of UINavigationBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a PDF file explaining what you are looking for:
http://dznr.org/be14